# Why was the value of a global variable being altered when I didn't program it to (strange behavior)?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

Before I begin I'd like to say I found a way round this, I just want to know WHY this was happening.

Ok, I'll try and explain this as simply as possible.

I was writing a chess game, and what I done is that I created a nested list whereby the third value will either be  None type OR the name of a picture (e.g "bq.png") which adheres to a piece - black queen. Don't ask why I done this, it's just the way I'm doing my chess game.

But in order for me to map this out, I needed a list with all None types in their third values like this to start off:

```
PROTO_BOARD=[
         [0,0,None],  [39,0,None],   [79,0,None], [119,0,None],    [159,0,None],   [199,0,None],   [239,0,None],   [279,0,None],
         [0,40,None], [39,40,None],  [79,40,None],[119,40,None],   [159,40,None],  [199,40,None],  [239,40,None],  [279,40,None],
         [0,80,None], [39,80,None],  [79,80,None], [119,80,None],  [159,80,None],  [199,80,None],  [239,80,None],  [279,80,None],
         [0,120,None],[39,120,None], [79,120,None],[119,120,None], [159,120,None], [199,120,None], [239,120,None], [279,120,None],
         [0,160,None],[39,160,None], [79,160,None],[119,160,None], [159,160,None], [199,160,None], [239,160,None], [279,160,None],
         [0,200,None],[39,200,None], [79,200,None],[119,200,None], [159,200,None], [199,200,None], [239,200,None], [279,200,None],
         [0,240,None],[39,240,None], [79,240,None],[119,240,None], [159,240,None], [199,240,None], [239,240,None], [279,240,None],
         [0,280,None],[39,280,None], [79,280,None],[119,280,None], [159,280,None], [199,280,None], [239,280,None], [279,280,None]

            ]
```

PROTO_BOARD is a global variable, and with it I had another global variable called current_board that was blank when I first create it. Now...

```
global current_board,PROTO_BOARD,PICS
current_board=PROTO_BOARD


for piece in self.all_pieces:
  x=piece.rect.x
  y=piece.rect.y
  for i in current_board:
   if i[0]==x and i[1]==y:
     location_1=current_board.index(i)
     location_2=PICS.index(piece.picture)
     current_board[location_1][2]=PICS[location_2]
```

The above is pretty self explanatory. The third element in the list can be changed if the picture matches up to the x and y coordinates of the actual piece (so if on coordinate (0,0) there's a black rook, the first element in current_board will then become 0,0,"br.png").
BUT the major problem with the above, is that PROTO_BOARD would become whatever current_board becomes, meaning it could have something like "bq.png" when all its third values are meant to be Nones.

Now my code works fine if I do this:

```
current_board=[
         [0,0,None],  [39,0,None],   [79,0,None], [119,0,None],    [159,0,None],   [199,0,None],   [239,0,None],   [279,0,None],
         [0,40,None], [39,40,None],  [79,40,None],[119,40,None],   [159,40,None],  [199,40,None],  [239,40,None],  [279,40,None],
         [0,80,None], [39,80,None],  [79,80,None], [119,80,None],  [159,80,None],  [199,80,None],  [239,80,None],  [279,80,None],
         [0,120,None],[39,120,None], [79,120,None],[119,120,None], [159,120,None], [199,120,None], [239,120,None], [279,120,None],
         [0,160,None],[39,160,None], [79,160,None],[119,160,None], [159,160,None], [199,160,None], [239,160,None], [279,160,None],
         [0,200,None],[39,200,None], [79,200,None],[119,200,None], [159,200,None], [199,200,None], [239,200,None], [279,200,None],
         [0,240,None],[39,240,None], [79,240,None],[119,240,None], [159,240,None], [199,240,None], [239,240,None], [279,240,None],
         [0,280,None],[39,280,None], [79,280,None],[119,280,None], [159,280,None], [199,280,None], [239,280,None], [279,280,None]
    ]
```

But I thought it would be easier to just make current_board equal to PROTO_BOARD, but then this caused PROTO_BOARD to change in value. It's something to do with the for loop, but I didn't even so much as time PROTO_BOARD, so why would its value change? Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: When you do `A=B` with objects in Python, you don't make a copy... you make a "reference".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do A=B with objects in Python, you don't make a copy... you make a "reference".

See this sample:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[1]=5
>>> a
[1, 5, 3]
>>>
```

Now do you understand what was happening?